# nullError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ksr-ca-qmaltjira.ca.kronos.com ksr-ca-qmaltjira.ca.kronos.com:8061

Tags: node.js, rest, ssl, jira, jira-rest-api

Keep getting **nullError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ksr-ca-qmaltjira.ca.kronos.com ksr-ca-qmaltjira.ca.kronos.com:8061** as my error when fetching data in my deploayed web-server. In **example.herokuapp.com/jiraWIPCRs** the data is empty and i receive the null error. However in my **localhost:2000/jiraWIPCRs** the data is displayed.

The full URL i am trying to create a rest api with is 
http://ksr-ca-qmaltjira.ca.kronos.com:8061

```
const base64 = require('base-64');
const JiraClient = require('jira-connector');

const jira = new JiraClient( {
host: 'ksr-ca-qmaltjira.ca.kronos.com',
protocol: 'http',
basic_auth: {
base64: base64.encode("username:password")
},
port: 8061

});

//endpoint
app.get('/jiraWIPCRs', (req, res) =>{

jira.search.search({
jql: ' "ECR #" != NULL AND "status" != Accepted AND "status" != Canceled AND 
"type" = "Change Request" AND "project"="Customer Support"',
maxResults: 5000
}, function(error, issue) {
res.send(issue);
});

});

const port = process.env.PORT || 2000;

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log("App is running on port " + port);
});
```